# Refreshing icon cache without closing explorer.exe

Tags: batch-file

I wrote this little code to set a folder icon:

```
@echo off
If [%1] == [] goto :eof
echo [.ShellClassInfo] > %1\Desktop.ini
echo IconFile=FolderIcon.ico >> %1\Desktop.ini
echo IconIndex=0 >> %1\Desktop.ini
for %%f in (%1\*.ico) do (
    if "%%~xf"==".ico" ren "%%f" "FolderIcon.ico" & attrib +h +s %1\"FolderIcon.ico"
)
attrib +S +H %1\desktop.ini
```

I've tried :

```
Nircmd.exe sysrefresh
Nircmd.exe shellrefresh
ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
ie4uinit.exe -show
```

but these don't have any effect
the only thing that kinda works is

```
taskkill /fi "imagename eq explorer.exe" /f
CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
DEL IconCache.db /a
START explorer.exe
```

this kills explorer (which is not ideal in my case)
none of these works if the folder is not on the desktop (even if you drag a folder that is inside a folder on desktop it won't work)

Answer (score 0):

so I found it

the folder itself needs to be read-only and system

```
attrib +R +S %1
```

refreshing after a minute will show the change